# Showing all the data in TradingChart

Tags: plotting

I was looking at the documentation of ploting `TradingChart` such as `TradingChart[{"SP500", {{2009, 1, 1}, {2009, 12, 31}}}]`. Here you have to specify the exact start date and end date. Is it possible to plot all the data that is available with something like `All`? I want all the data but i don't know how far back Mathematica has the data available for it. Finding out with trial and error would be a very time consuming process. Is there a way i can find out how far back the data goes as in the first date avaliable for that symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, this should work, but it does not. It returns YTD data only.

```
TradingChart["SP500", All]
```

Workaround

```
data = FinancialData["SP500", "OHLCV", All];

data["FirstDate"]
(* DateObject[{1950, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.] *)

TradingChart[data]
```